# Performance of Passing Collections VS Multiple Objects in Loop

Tags: .net, performance, loops, oop

When passing parameters to an object's method in a loop, is it better to call the object's method repeatedly passing in a single value each time or call the method once passing a collection?
Please see the following pseudocode:

Option A:

```
SetProperties(myObject)
{

    webelementCollection = Selenium code to scrape a webpage and return a collection of webelements

    foreach webelement in webelementCollection
    {
        key = get key value from webelement
        value = get value value from webelement

        //Set each object property one at a time
        myObject.SetProperty (key, value)
    }
}
```

Option B:

```
SetProperties(myObject)
{

    webelementCollection = Selenium code to scrape a webpage and return a collection of webelements
    collectionObj = Key/value storage object: list of KVP or dictionary of strings

    foreach webelement in webelementCollection
    {
        key = get key value from webelement
        value = get value value from webelement

        //Store each key & value for future use
        collectionObj.Add(key,value)
    }

    //Itterate over the collection in the method to set all properties for the object
    myObject.SetAllProperties (collectionObj)
}
```

The result of running the SetProperties method in the pseduocode is that "myObject" now has all it's properties filled in from a list of fields on a webpage.  The SetProperty/SetAllProperties method will actually set the object’s properties.

From reading other StackOverflow posts on the topic of premature optimization, I realize the answer is that it probably doesn’t matter at this stage, especially in non-production code, but I still would like to know if there is a best practices in this situation.

BTW:
I'm currently using a mixture of Option A & B, which inspired me to post this question.  When scraping data from the webpage Option A is used to populate objects.  After saving the fields and values to a database, I use Option B restore the objects the next time the program is run.

The code is written in C#. I don't think language should be that important to the answer, since this is a general object oriented question.

Also, the SetProperty method in my application uses reflection to actually set the object’s properties.  Using reflection to avoid writing numerous case statements on the key value:  (  case: “fname” this.fname = value,  case: “lname” this.lname = value , ect.  ).  I realize that if I was truly concerned about about performance I should hard code all the values.

Edit based on Slai's comment: To clarify my query, I was debating whether it would be better to call a method X number of times passing a single parameter, or calling the method once passing a collection containing X number of parameters.  Both approaches would need to use a loop to perform some action on each parameter, but where's the best place to put the loop?  Is there more overhead involved in calling a method X number times or in initializing and populating a collection object?  I was wondering if there are any best practices or coding standards that cover this situation.

Comment: but SetAllProperties will still have to loop to set the properties, so probably about the same (might be a tiny bit slower because of creating the key value object overhead)

Comment: if SetAllProperties doesn't use reflection, then of course it would be much faster than using reflection .. but it's not clear what is different in the  methods implementation